# html5 video only works in safari

Tags: html, video, safari

Im new to HTML 5 and learning from w3schools

I tries to get the html video code working for a file I have. Trouble is that the html only works in safari but not the other browsers I have.

Any ideas please?

thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="candonjoel.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="candonjoel.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="candonjoel.ogg" type="video/ogg" />

Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which other browsers did this not work in (include specific versions please)?

Answer (score 0):

Does candonjoel.webm exist? Can you show the URL of your code please?

https://github.com/kaihendry/recordmydesktop2.0/ is project to make screencasts easier from Linux to all browsers.